# Set gain and expsoure without DisplayPropertyPage (Aforge, Directshow)

Tags: web-config, webcam, directshow, aforge, webcam-capture

can anyone tell me how I can change gain or exposure with directshow from Afroge.

I already tried what you can see below but didn't succeed. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

using AForge.Video;
using AForge.Video.DirectShow;

...
...

VideoCaptureDevice videoSource;

private void changeProp(int value)
{
videoSource.SetCameraProperty(CameraControlProperty.Exposure, value, CameraControlFlags.Auto);
}

Comment: Hi. Did you find an answer?

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me. Most of the code taken from Afroge Samples.

```
private VideoCaptureDevice videoDevice;
private FilterInfoCollection videoDevices;
private VideoCapabilities[] videoCapabilities;

public Bool SetCamera(Cameras camera, int camDevice, CameraResolution camResolution,
        int exposureValue, int zoomValue, int focusValue)
    {
        // Enumerate video devices
        videoDevices = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);

        //Select camera according to specified index
        videoDevice = new VideoCaptureDevice(videoDevices[camDevice].MonikerString);

        //Get video capabilities for setting the resoluton
            videoCapabilities = videoDevice.VideoCapabilities;

            if (camera == Cameras.C910)
            {
                switch (camResolution)
                {
                    case CameraResolution.A_640x480:
                        videoDevice.VideoResolution = videoCapabilities[0];
                        break;
                    case CameraResolution.B_800x600:
                        videoDevice.VideoResolution = videoCapabilities[14];
                        break;
                    case CameraResolution.C_960x720:
                        videoDevice.VideoResolution = videoCapabilities[16];
                        break;
                    case CameraResolution.D_1280x720:
                        videoDevice.VideoResolution = videoCapabilities[17];
                        break;
                    case CameraResolution.E_1920x1080:
                        videoDevice.VideoResolution = videoCapabilities[24];
                        break;
                    default:
                        videoDevice.VideoResolution = videoCapabilities[0];
                        break;
                }

            }
            else if (camera == Cameras.C920)
            {
                switch (camResolution)
                {
                    case CameraResolution.A_640x480:
                        videoDevice.VideoResolution = videoCapabilities[0];
                        break;
                    case CameraResolution.B_800x600:
                        videoDevice.VideoResolution = videoCapabilities[10];
                        break;
                    case CameraResolution.C_960x720:
                        videoDevice.VideoResolution = videoCapabilities[12];
                        break;
                    case CameraResolution.D_1280x720:
                        videoDevice.VideoResolution = videoCapabilities[14];
                        break;
                    case CameraResolution.E_1920x1080:
                        videoDevice.VideoResolution = videoCapabilities[16];
                        break;
                    default:
                        videoDevice.VideoResolution = videoCapabilities[0];
                        break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                videoDevice.VideoResolution = videoCapabilities[0];
            }

        try
        {   
            videoDevice.SetCameraProperty(
                CameraControlProperty.Zoom,
                zoomValue,
                CameraControlFlags.Manual);

            videoDevice.SetCameraProperty(
                CameraControlProperty.Focus,
                focusValue,
                CameraControlFlags.Manual);

            videoDevice.SetCameraProperty(
                CameraControlProperty.Exposure,
                exposureValue,
                CameraControlFlags.Manual);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.show(ex.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: That is awesome but how do I do this from a UWP app?  It doesn't seem like I can use the AForge nuget package and the default stuff is returning 'Brightness', 'Exposure', etc. as unsupported.  But it is supported in DirectShow.  So how do I do it?  When I try calling DirectShow it just crashes.  It is a UVC camera and it works fine with DirectShow for changing the camera properties but I cannot get it to work in UWP.  And I have a pretty big app at this point but I can rewrite it in C++ if that's the only way?